# How do I delete an amino acid residue from a loop and then join the loose ends?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure

I want to delete an amino acid residue from a loop and then join the loose ends. I intend to increase the thermal stability of the protein by reducing the size of the loop and its agitation. Pymol just deletes the residue and breaks the loop.

I intend to increase the optimal temperature of the protein, even if it costs some reduction in activity. The objective is to reduce protein agitation due to temperature increase. I will try point mutations that increase hydrogen interactions and eventually delete a loop located glycine to reduce its length and consequently its thermal agitation. All this work is aimed at preserving the catalytic site, but some loss of activity is acceptable.

As a complement to my question, I present an excerpt from the paper by Mahdie Rahban et al (2022) ; Thermal stability enhancement: Fundamental concepts of protein engineering strategies to manipulate the flexible structure.

> Loop deletion or shortening by insertion of proline or deletion of
> Gly, coupled with loop anchoring by increasing the number of salt
> bridges, hydrogen bonds, or hydrophobicity, are good strategies to
> enhance the overall rigidity of a protein conformation leading to
> better compactness and a decreased number of internal cavities.

Comment: Does anyone have a suggestion how to solve this problem? I already used Modeller to insert an amino acid residue in place of a deleterious mutation, could Modeller be used to reconstruct the loop? How do I do it?

Comment: Modeller .. no thats for point mutations

Comment: https://salilab.org/modeller/9.15/manual.pdf 2.3 Loop optimization pag 26

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what software you have in hand and want to use. But basically, when you delete/add a residue, you can't just stick two parts together since it affects the whole conformation.

I suggest using AlphaFold2, and input it with different sequences (including deletion mutation) to see how it affects the structure.

Here is a link to AF2 colab:
https://colab.research.google.com/github/sokrypton/ColabFold/blob/main/AlphaFold2.ipynb